# Is the the shift functor exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, module-isomorphism

Given a cochain complex $C^{\bullet}$, are the notations $H^p(C^{\bullet}[n])$ and $H^p(C^{\bullet})[n]$ equivalent or do they differ? We know that $H^p(C^{\bullet}[n])=H^{p+n}(C^{\bullet})$ but $H^p(C^{\bullet})[n]$ seems to have two different interpretations. The first interpretation is as the cohomology group $H^{p}(C^{\bullet})$ concentrated in degree $-n$ and the second interpretation is $H^p(C^{\bullet})[n]=H^{n+p}(C^{\bullet})$. Or are both interpretations equivalent even though I do not see them as equivalent? Can someone elaborate on the different points of view.

Comment: Can you give any examples of places where the second interpretation has been used?

Comment: For example, in the definition (Definition 4.8) of the Chen-Ruan cohomology on page 86 of the book https://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/teaching/Orbifolds/Ruan.pdf. But you can see this in every paper on Chen-Ruan cohomology.

Comment: I have never seen the second usage. I would argue that it is incorrect. The correct way to get the same result would be to write $H^p(C^{\bullet}[n])=H^{n+p}(C^{\bullet})$.

Comment: @IDC I'd also never seen it, but the OP is correct in saying that it is used in the book he links to in comments (not so sure about "in every paper on Chen-Ruan cohomology": I looked at a few and didn't find it). I agree with you that the usage is incorrect, or at least very eccentric: whatever $H^p(C^\bullet)[n]$ means, it should be something that depends on $H^p(C^\bullet)$ and $n$.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard, Thanks for the comment. Indeed, in most papers, authors write for the Chen-ruan cohomology $\oplus_{(g)}H^{d-2a(g)}(X^g)^{C(g)}$, where $a(g)$is the age function and $C(g)$ is the centraliser of $g$ in $G$. However, since $a(g)$ is not an integer but a rational number, the only way $H^{d-2a(g)}(X^g)$ makes sense is to assume that it actually means $H^d(X^g)[-2a(g)]$. So most papers seem to use the notation in question in disguise.